# nopcommerce MVC Route Explain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, nopcommerce

When run nopcommerce 2.4.0, the link I get is `localhost:7725/c/2/computers` instead of `localhost:7725/categories/2/computers`

I don't know where is the code convert **categories** to **c**

Please help me to learn MVC via nopcommerce.

Answer (score 9):

1. Open `\Presentation\Nop.Web\Infrastructure\RouteProvider.cs` file
2. Find

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Category",
                 "**c**/{categoryId}/{SeName}",
                 new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category", SeName = UrlParameter.Optional },
                 new { categoryId = @"\d+" },
                 new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

and replace it with

```
routes.MapLocalizedRoute("Category",
                            "categories/{categoryId}/{SeName}",
                            new { controller = "Catalog", action = "Category", SeName = UrlParameter.Optional },
                            new { categoryId = @"\d+" },
                            new[] { "Nop.Web.Controllers" });
```

3. Do almost the same in `\Libraries\Nop.Services\Seo\SitemapGenerator.cs` file (replace `{0}c/{1}/{2}` with `{0}categories/{1}/{2}`)

Comment: Thanks was trying to figure out where all the routes are in NopCommerce